# Tensorflow JS Model- Hyperparameter Tune

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow.js

I am currently using Tensorflow JS body pix model to carry out the task of Virtual Backgroud for my application, However, the performance is not at par and the mask does not perfectly fit the body.

**Are there ways I can improve this using some post-processing steps? Is there any way I can smoothen the mask in JavaScript?**

**Can I use transfer learning or maybe retrain or hyperparameter tune the TFjs model using my own annotated data? or is it just an API and won't be able to do much?**

Please go through the image below for results. ignore the orientation of the background image for now.

Currently using this [model](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2019/11/updated-bodypix-2.html) and these are the parameters:

```
 outputStride: 16, 
 multiplier: 0.75, 
 quantBytes: 2

 flipHorizontal: false,
 internalResolution: 'medium',
 segmentationThreshold: 0.7
```

[image]